# How to upload an image to FTP without mulitpart only on FTP client

Tags: angularjs, cordova, file-upload, ionic-framework, ftp

I am trying to upload an image to my FTP what i have done so far is i have successfully invoked the image and i have the image location in

```
file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.ftptranfer949961/cache/1467013143014.png
```

i have to send the **.png** image file to my FTP

```
 var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})


app.service('MyService',function(){
  var imgPath = [];
  //var imgName = [];
  this.getImgPath = function(){
    return imgPath;
  }
  this.setImgPath = function(path){
    console.log(path);
    imgPath = path ;

  /*this.getImgName = function(){
    return imgName;
  }
  this.setImgName = function(pass){
    console.log(pass);
    imgName = pass;
  }*/

  }
});

//https://github.com/xfally/cordova-plugin-ftp

app.controller('mycontroller',function($scope,$cordovaCamera,$cordovaFileTransfer,MyService,$log,$timeout,$window){

  $scope.takePicture = function(){

    var options = { 
            quality : 75, 
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            allowEdit : false,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
            mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
            targetWidth: 250,
            targetHeight: 250,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true
        };
 
    

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageURI) {
          console.log('invokeing cordovaCamera');
          $scope.image =  imageURI;
         //  imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
          console.log(imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1));
          
           MyService.setImgPath(imageURI);
          console.log($scope.image);
          console.log(imageURI);
          $scope.upload();        
        }, function(err) {
            // An error occured. Show a message to the user
            console.log(err);
        });
        
    };

    $scope.upload =function(){

       var ping = MyService.getImgPath().substr(MyService.getImgPath().lastIndexOf('/')+1);
       console.log(ping);

      // Test code (for angularjs)
// Tip: Usually init/create $window.cordova.plugin.ftp will take some time, so set a `timeout()` to make sure it's ready.
//      But surely, the best and safest way is to listen `deviceready` event for cordova, or `$ionicPlatform.ready()` for ionic.
//      You can find more info in official docs of cordova or ionic.
$timeout(function() {
    if ($window.cordova.plugin.ftp) {
        $log.log("xtest: ftp: found");
        // 1. connect to one ftp server, then you can do any actions/cmds
        $window.cordova.plugin.ftp.connect("308.3d8.myftpupload.com", "wepopusers", "Chandru@123", function() {
            $log.log("xtest: ftp: connect ok");
            // 2. list one dir, note that just can be dir, not file
            $window.cordova.plugin.ftp.ls("/gopi", function(fileList) {
                $log.log("xtest: ftp: list ok");
                if (fileList && fileList.length > 0) {
                    $log.log("xtest: ftp: The last file'name is " + fileList[fileList.length - 1].name);
                    $log.log("xtest: ftp: The last file'type is " + fileList[fileList.length - 1].type);
                    $log.log("xtest: ftp: The last file'link is " + fileList[fileList.length - 1].link);
                    $log.log("xtest: ftp: The last file'size is " + fileList[fileList.length - 1].size);
                    $log.log("xtest: ftp: The last file'modifiedDate is " + fileList[fileList.length - 1].modifiedDate);
                   
                      // 4. upload local file to remote, you can rename at the same time. arg1: local file, arg2: remote file.
                      // make sure you can access and read the local file.
                      $window.cordova.plugin.ftp.upload("/" + ping, "/gopi/" + ping, function(percent) {
                          console.log(percent);
                            if (percent == 1) {
                                $log.log("xtest: ftp: upload finish");
                       
                               
                            } else {
                                $log.log("xtest: ftp: upload percent=" + percent*100 + "%");
                            }
                        }, function(error) {
                            $log.log("xtest: ftp: upload error=" + error);
                        });
                }
            }, function(error) {
                $log.log("xtest: ftp: list error: " + error);
            });
        });
    } else {
        $log.log("xtest: ftp: not found!");
    }
}, 2000);
    };

  });
```

you can see in this line

> $window.cordova.plugin.ftp.upload("/ping", "/gopi/ping", function(percent)

**/ping** in this i have the image name **1467013143014.png**

but i am getting the error as

> xtest: ftp: upload error=java.io.FileNotFoundException: /ping

For more details look this git-hub [cordova-ftp](https://github.com/xfally/cordova-plugin-ftp) .

i have successfully uploaded one file named **default.prop** to my **FTP** but i dont know how it is uploaded to my ftp other then any thing what i have given to my FTP i am not able to upload it

I have even hot code my path of the image in my upload area but not able to upload an image.

how can i access the file of my image and upload to my FTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing i notice is that your ping variable holds the file path. Hence you cannot use `"/ping"` as it will be treated as a string not variable. Try `"/" + ping`.

Also your ping variable just holds the file path not name. So try using `"/" + ping + FILE_NAME`

To avoid hard coding the path, try using cordova file plugin. In your case, after installing the plugin, try using `cordova.file.applicationDirectory` or `cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory` which will give you the path you are looking to harcode. More info on file path is available in the [official file plugin link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files). Hope it helps.